# TCP write() prints char* to itself rather than to buffer only on first socket connection, but works OK on second connection onwards

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

On the first connection to the Server socket by a Client, the Server prints the output to itself, and leaves the Client blocked. But the second Client onwards receives the output from the Server.
The buffer that is expected to output to the Client is the server uptime.

Why does this happen, is there a way to immediately send the output to the Client and not block it?

To replicate, run 'ruptimeServer' on one terminal, and run 'ruptimeClient [localIPAddress] [serverIPAddress]'.

Below is an example of the I/O to the Server.

```
[user@linux-3 Lab2]$ ./ruptimeServer 
Awaiting connection.
 20:42:05 up 2 days, 17:38,  5 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.06  <-- buffer
Write Success
Awaiting connection.
Write Success
Awaiting connection.
Write Success
Awaiting connection.
^CCaught Ctrl+C, closing all connections.
```

Below is the I/O to the Client.

```
[user@linux-3 Lab2]$ ./ruptimeClient 127.0.0.1 10.24.87.66
Connection Success.
^C
[user@linux-3 Lab2]$ ./ruptimeClient 127.0.0.1 10.24.87.66
Connection Success.
10.24.87.66:  20:42:14 up 2 days, 17:38,  5 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.06
[user@linux-3 Lab2]$ ./ruptimeClient 127.0.0.1 10.24.87.66
Connection Success.
10.24.87.66:  20:42:18 up 2 days, 17:38,  5 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.06
```

Below is the code for Server.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

char* get_uptime();
void sig_handl(int sig_num);
int sersock, consock;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr, clientaddr;
    struct sigaction sigIntHandler;
    int on = 1;

    sigIntHandler.sa_handler = sig_handl;
    sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
    sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;

    char input_buffer[1024] = {0};
    int len = sizeof(clientaddr);

    char* IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.254.11";

    if((sersock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
        perror("socket() error");
        exit(1);
    }

    serveraddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(28189);
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if(bind(sersock, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0){
        perror("bind() error");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(listen(sersock, 10) < 0){
        perror("listen() error");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *output;
    output = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handl);
    while(1){
        printf("Awaiting connection.\n");
        if(consock = accept(sersock, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &len) < 0){
            perror("accept() error");
            exit(1);
        }
        output = get_uptime();
        if(write(consock, output, 1024) < 0){
            perror("write() error");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Write Success\n");
        close(consock);
    }
    close(sersock); 
}

char * get_uptime(){        //returns uptime on server
    char *buffer;
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
    FILE* file = popen("uptime", "r");
    fgets(buffer, 100, file);
    pclose(file);

    return buffer;
}

void sig_handl(int sig_num){
    printf("Caught Ctrl+C, closing all connections.\n");
    close(consock);
    close(sersock);
    exit(0);
}
```

Below is the code for Client.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc != 3){
        printf("Not enough arguments. To run, \"./ruptimeClient <localhost_IP> <server_IP>\"\n");
        return 0;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in remoteaddr;
    char input_buffer[100];
    //input_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    int clisock;
    char* SERVER_IP = argv[2];

    if((clisock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
        perror("socket() error");
        exit(1);
    }

    remoteaddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    remoteaddr.sin_port = htons(28189);
    remoteaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_IP);

    if(connect(clisock, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr, sizeof(remoteaddr)) < 0){
        perror("Connection failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Connection Success.\n");
    if(read(clisock, input_buffer, 100) < 0){
        perror("read() error");
        exit(1);
    }
    //input_buffer = "test";
    printf("%s: %s", SERVER_IP, input_buffer);
    close(clisock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but worth mentioning anyway: your code leaks memory like crazy and has unreachable code.

Comment: Noted, thanks for the input. I'll manage the memory and remove unused code.

Comment: It would be better to have `get_uptime()` write into a char array supplied by the caller, and get rid of all the `malloc()`s altogether.

Comment: compiling the server code with: `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` results in 11 warning messages, of which several are critical.  Also, the posted code for the server is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`  to expose the prototype for the function: `close()`  strongly suggest fixing the code, so it cleanly compiles,  Then start working on the problems with the logic of the program

Comment: this statement: `output = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);`  is allocating dynamic memory for a pointer that will be overlayed by the call to: `get_uptime()`  This results in a memory leak as the pointer to the `malloc`d memory will be overlayed

Comment: this statement: `if( write( consock, output, 1024) < 0 )`  causes 1024 bytes to be written to the client, but much of that will be garbage.  Suggest: `if( write( consock, output, strlen( output ) ) < 0 )`

Comment: in function: `get_uptime()`, these statements: `char *buffer;
    buffer = malloc( 1024 );`  result in a memory leak and are a total waste of cpu cycles and resources.  Suggest allocating the buffer as: `char buffer[1024];` in the function that calls `get_uptime()`  and passing the address of that buffer to the function: `get_uptime()`

Comment: There is a long list of functions that should not be called in a signal handler.  `printf()` is one of those functions that should not be called

Comment: the client code is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>` to expose the prototype for the function: `read()`

Comment: the client code is missing the statements: `#include <arpa/inet.h>` for the function: `inet_addr()`

Comment: in the client code: regarding the statement: `printf("Not enough arguments. To run, \"./ruptimeClient <localhost_IP> <server_IP>\"\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Usually when the command line parameters are not correct, a USAGE statement is output, similar to:    `fprintf( stderr,  "USAGE: %s <localhost_IP> <server_IP>\"\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: in the code block: `if(argc != 3){`  The statement: `return 0;` indicates Success.  But the return is due to an error.  Suggest: `return 1;`  or better: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: in the client code: regarding: `if(read(clisock, input_buffer, 100) < 0){`  Since the server could be sending a message that is (up to) 1024 bytes in length, that `100` should be replaced with `1024`

Comment: The `read()` function does not NUL terminate the input, so should be saving the returned value from `read()`  (it has type `ssize_t`) and then use the statement: `input_buffer[ that returned value ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: ` printf("%s: %s", SERVER_IP, input_buffer);`  this data will sit in the stream stdout buffer until the program exits.  Much better to include a trailing new line so the data is immediately output to the terminal, similar to: `printf("%s: %s\n", SERVER_IP, input_buffer);`  Note the addition of the '\n' to the format string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if(consock = accept(sersock, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &len) < 0){
```

That's parsed as if you wrote this:

```
if(consock = (accept(sersock, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &len) < 0)){
```

As a result, `consock` ends up getting set to `0`, which when interpreted as a file descriptor, means standard input. This then gets closed after the first client (the one that hangs), so it's available for subsequent clients, which then get reassigned that now-free FD number. To fix it, add explicit parentheses, like this:

```
if((consock = accept(sersock, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &len)) < 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. is for the server
2. cleanly compiles
3. does not leak memory
4. incorporates the comments to the OPs question

and now, the proposed code for the server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


char* get_uptime( char *buffer, int size );
void sig_handl(int sig_num);
int sersock, consock;


int main( void )
{
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr, clientaddr;
    struct sigaction sigIntHandler;
    //int on = 1;

    sigIntHandler.sa_handler = sig_handl;
    sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
    sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;

    //char input_buffer[1024] = {0};
    socklen_t  len = sizeof(clientaddr);

    //char* IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.254.11";

    if((sersock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("socket() error");
        exit(1);
    }

    serveraddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(28189);
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if(bind(sersock, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind() error");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(sersock, 10) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen() error");
        exit(1);
    }

    char *output;
    int size = 1024;
    char buffer[ size ];

    signal(SIGINT, sig_handl);

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Awaiting connection.\n");
        if( (consock = accept(sersock, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &len)) < 0)
        {
            perror("accept() error");
            exit(1);
        }

        output = get_uptime( buffer, size );

        if( write( consock, output, strlen( output ) ) < 0 )
        {
            perror("write() error");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Write Success\n");
        close(consock);
    }
    close(sersock); 
}


char * get_uptime( char *buffer, int size )
{        //returns uptime on server

    FILE* file = popen("uptime", "r");
    fgets( buffer, size, file );
    pclose(file);

    return buffer;
}


void sig_handl(int sig_num)
{
    (void)sig_num;
    printf("Caught Ctrl+C, closing all connections.\n");
    close(consock);
    close(sersock);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Why return the address of the buffer that the caller already knows because he supplied it?

Comment: @user207421,  Not necessary to return the address of the buffer.   I just did that to minimize the changes to the OPs posted code.